# Can I configure the Keycloak Spring Boot adapter so that it populates the user principal even on requests that don't require authorization?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

If I have an endpoint which should be publically available but behave differently if you're logged in, I can't specify it in the `security-constraints` section of my application configuration (otherwise if I'm not logged in I can't reach the endpoint at all). But without it being listed there, the user principal never gets populated on the request, even if a valid Bearer token is provided in the Authorization header.

Is there a way to get the behaviour I want with the basic Spring Boot adapter? If not, am I likely to have more luck with the Spring Security adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this is to enable preemptive authentication in the Tomcat context. Assuming you're deploying using the embedded server, you can implement a `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` as follows:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PreemptiveAuthWebServerCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory>
{
    @Override
    public void customize( final TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory )
    {
        factory.addContextCustomizers( context -> context.setPreemptiveAuthentication( true ) );
    }
}
```

Now if a request has an Authorization header sent, it will always be processed even if the request isn't explicitly behind a path which requires authorization.